# How to match devide ID to install apk?

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to install my app only on some devices and does not allow installation on another devices.

I thought that maybe I can pair a unique ID to install apps.

**I can do this?**

**How I can block the installation of a single application on some devices?**

Comment: This is not a good idea.  The reason is does not exist in a platform implementation is because in the history of similar schemes, it is always the legitimate user who loses the most.  The thieves will simply find a way around your scheme. So I buy your app, install it. and I'm happy.  I backup my phone to the cloud and later, my phone fails with a hardware fault.  The manufacturer replaces it, I restore from the backup and now my app doesn't work.  What  now?

Comment: @Simon It is a private application, is not going to sell, so needed only I could install on my device but a user already gave me an idea, although I understand your point of view and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control app installation based on Device Id (IMEI) either by google play store or direct install... However you can check at the start of the launcher activity, you can check that the Device Id (or Imei) is in the list of imei you are allowing... Then allow user to use the apk... ELSE finish() the launcher activity... You can also give message to user stating "Unauthorized access" or something similar...

Comment: Mmm, good idea, thanks. Or maybe ¿I can unistall apk programatically?

Comment: You can do that, but you will need to send intent to uninstall dialog for doing that... You can not just wipe out the apk... User will need to say "Yes" to uninstall anyway...

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that maybe I can pair a unique ID to install app

There's no platform provided, reliable uniquie ID of the device.

> How I can block the installation of a single application on some devices?

You cannot block installation on device - as long as device meets your manifest requirements (screen, libs, platform version etc) user will be able to install your app.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides you with this option also. If you have an account in the developer console of android, in the apk column you can see the list of devices your app supports. Out of that you can deselect the ones you don't want in your list.

At the time you are uploading the apk to play store, its very easy to deselect the devices you don't want your app to run on.